# The underlying connection was closed on downloading the file from library

Tags: 2010, document-library

I am using below code to download the file in specific folder from SharePoint 2010 Document library.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(SPDocURL), "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\" + dt.Rows[0]["FileLeafRef"]);
```

But I am getting the below error message.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

The same code in working fine on my DEV environment but it is not working in my Production Environment.

Comment: May be error is because of timeout problem. You can increase the timeout time. May be this link will help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/826210

Comment: I already did that.